# How to test a boolean in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have a powershell script which looks to make sure someone is running the script as an admin.

The variable $currentPrincipal returns true or false.

Here is the code:

```
$currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)

If ($currentPrincipal -eq $true) {

    Write-host "yay"
}
Else {

   Write-Host "boo"

}
```

But when running as an admin AND currentPrincipal is true, it still falls through to the else... here is the CLI which shows that:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> C:\Users\dogzilla\Desktop\SetSQLServerToManual.ps1
True
boo
```

My question is, what is the proper way to evaluate a boolean in powershell?

Comment: Will putting `#Requires -RunAsAdministrator` at top of your script work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-6

Comment: Why would $currentPrincipal be $true?

Comment: @KoryGill... requires runasadministrator is not compatible with all versions of powershell.  So the solution in the post is more portable.

Comment: @js2010  It's true because I'm running it in a terminal opened with "run as administrator".  The output from the CLI says "true" as well -- I copied and pasted that directly from the terminal.

Comment: $true doesn't come from $currentPrincipal.  It comes from running the method  $currentPrincipal.IsInRole(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your currently just calling [`WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole?view=netframework-4.8), which will output the `Boolean` result. Additionally, `$currentPrincipal` is of type `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal`, which is not a `Boolean`. I would ammend your code to store the result of `IsInRole()` as a variable and checking that instead.

```
$currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$checkRole = $currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)

If ($checkRole -eq $true) {
    Write-host "yay"
}
Else {
    Write-Host "boo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to test it:

```
if ( ($currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) -eq $true )
```